# Calling a column within database. I'm workin on django for python

Tags: python, django, sqlite, bootstrap-4

I am currently stuck on program wherein it will output all the post that has a value of `category_id == 1` within the table. I can't seem to call the said function can you guys help? thank you it will be fully appreciated.

```
{% for knowledgepost in kposts %}
  <article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ knowledgepost.author }}</a>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ knowledgepost.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
      </div>
            <h3><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'knowledge-detail' knowledgepost.id %}">{{ knowledgepost.title }}</a></h3>
++++++++ the line of code should be here+++++++++++
            <p class="article-content">{{ knowledgepost.content|safe|truncatewords:"50"|linebreaks }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
```

I expect the output to be able to call the column within the database

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to "call"?

Comment: Hi, i think you're stuck on a PHP way of performing queries in your view. This isn't really the way to go. Instead of that, create a GET method in your class view that accepts params such as category_id. In the template you'll have a selection of categories where you can set the GET and in the view use the GET method to get the values and return the context to your template.